# I can't save a file in Visual Studio Code which is checked out from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to edit a file that's checked in to TFS using Visual Studio Code, but even though I've checked it out (from within Visual Studio) I get an error when I try to save it: 
"Failed to save 'myfile.cfc': A system error occured (EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'd:...\myfile.cfc')".
I've tried different file types and ensured that the Read-only attribute is off on the file, but I still can't save anything. (I can do a Save-As and edit & save that file all I want, but of course I'm not going to do that).

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] and [ask] for information on how to best revise your post to meet the SO guidelines.

Comment: All the operations to a source-controlled file happen locally. You issue is not TFS related. Try on another PC, or create a new workspace to get the files.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the late reply - running VS Code as administrator fixed the problem.
Too bad it gives you a misleading error message.

Comment: This should be a comment or edit to the original question.

Comment: This should not be an acceptable answer: VSCode, which allows user-generated extensions that can do whatever the hell they please to your filesystem and OS installation, should **never** be run with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running VSCode as an admin explicitly? If not, and if UAC is enabled, this could cause the behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: it is a comment actually

Comment: What is UAC and how do you enabled it?

Comment: UAC is what short for User Account Control. When you select "Run as Administrator" you are using the UAC. Right-click and run VSCode as an admin and you should be fine.